# Excessive memory consumption, PHP using about 70mb of ram

Tags: php, memory, ram

Today I decided I would benchmark my forums software.  The software is 71Mb in size and I noticed it consuming over 50Mb!  Is that a lot for today's standard cause I don't know, I'm 13 years old and I don't know what to do?  I checked windows task manager and found the apache instance and every time I reload the website, it takes well over 10 seconds to load and then apache jumps from 8.7Mb to 189Mb for one user!  That's insane to me and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

**HOW THE SCRIPT WORKS** 
So first I have URL routing.  I first get all the pages by getting all the dirs in the pages dir, then I get stuff like this:

`REGISTER, SEARCH, FORUMS`

then I check all the dirs configs and get the URL, then I match the URL and the request URL in the app configs.  If they match, I include the App.php of them.  I have second URL parameters too but that info worn help.  all it's gonna do is check if the second param is defined then includes the name from the controllers' dir in the app folder.

then I have the templater engine that I also coded.  Yep no twig or smart, I hate those.
Now I also parse language on the page and they are defined like this:

`@register-fail-verify-notice @`

A lot is going on in the framework but then ontop is the forums, it is all split into apps.  I also noticed when I'm logged out, the page loads faster too,  Could this be because I fetch the base64 profile pic every time and base64 is so big it takes this much time.

That's about all I know, if you need any more information ill be glad to give it. Thanks for any support!

**EDIT**

Here's a video of it in action:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/799679786749263925/822147467846877254/02ae0c0654b34fe5a2944310e484957a12_38_46.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it.  It was cause my profile pic was in 4k, what I need to do is scale it down to about 512 px by 512 px to prevent the browser to process too much data, anyways, who in this world is zooming peoples profile pics to 10x size.